# CSS: Failing to display unless refreshed - Navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on navigation bar and the strangest issue is occurring.
Please use the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meaatp37/) link to see what I mean.

To duplicate the error:

1. Run the code when the desktop view is active i.e. when the navigation links are in a line.
2. Then resize the screen till the "click me" is displayed.
3. Then press it.
4. Now run the code while you see the "click me" and press it again.

JS information

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // UserCP 
    $('.rotate').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("down");
    });
    $('.nav-start').on('click', function() {
        $("#nav2").removeClass("hidden");
        $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideToggle('100');
        return false;
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideToggle('100');
    });

    $('body').on('click', function() {
        $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideUp('100');
    });
    $("#nav2 li a").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('#nav2 li a').length) {
            if ($('#nav2 li a').is(":visible")) {
                $('html, body').on('click', function() {
                    $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideUp('100');
                });
            };
        };
    });
});
```

FIXED - UPDATED [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz715fv5/)! Thanks @Louys Patrice Bessette @Titus @Rick

Comment: first I'd remove the `$(document).ready(function() {` you have inside the current `$(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: So what is the **intended** behaviour?

Comment: You've used the same ID for multiple elements and invalid closing tags `</il>` instead of `</li>` but the main problem seems to be that you call `$('#nav2 li a').stop().slideToggle('100');` when the menu is already shown.

Comment: It works perfectly if you refresh it when it's in "mobile mode" before using it. However if you go into desktop view and then downscale the screen it glitches out and opens and closes. The function rick suggested removing is there to prevent the page from staying open if the user switches pages.

Comment: @Titus @Rick `$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideToggle('100');
    });` Is there because the nav menu will automatically be opened on page load otherwise. even after removing this the same error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two click events on this "Click me" `li`...
(One on `.navstart` and one on `.rotate`)
It may not be an issue, but this make the code harder to read.

Then, when you `slideToggle()`, if you want the submenu to slide down, it has to be hidden.
Because, since you remove the `hidden` class (probably usefull on load), the submenu is visible.
A Toggle hides it.

I simplified your script to this.
Have a look at this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/ju8b8Lbf/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Show submenu on "Click me"
  $('.nav-start').on('click', function() {
    $('.rotate').toggleClass("down");
    $("#nav2").removeClass("hidden");
    var subNav = $('#nav2 li a');

    if(subNav.css("display")=="block"){
      subNav.stop().slideUp('100');
    }else{
      subNav.stop().slideDown('100');
    }
  return false;
  });


  $("#nav2 li a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Hide submenu on document click
  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#nav2 li a').length && $('#nav2 li a').is(":visible")) {
      $('#nav2 li a').stop().slideUp('100');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: One issue is see with this is it will only close if you double left click or click the body. I would like to be able to close it with the same button I use to open it (with a single click). Also noting back to an issue I was having earlier is that It will automatically open on page refresh. @Louys Patrice Bessette

Comment: I changed it slightly to have an open/close "click me".

Comment: Please disregard my last comment, I was able to fix my issue by 1 simplifying the CSS as I was using way to many ID tags @Titus Thank-you. 2 simplifying the JS @Louys Patrice Bessette @Rick Thank-you. Finally adding `$('#nav-mobile ul li a').stop().slideUp('100');` to the begging of the script after the Jquery(document) function that was all me :).